# Determining the number of threads per EPYC AMD 7601 cpu

Tags: amd, hyperthreading

I'm trying to confirm that my AMD EPYC 7601 CPUs are set up with dual threading.

I have 2 X 32 CPUs and ​should have 2 threads per CPU.

When I run:

```
lscpu | grep -E '^Thread|^Core|^Socket|^CPU\('
```

I get:

CPU(s):                64
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    32
Socket(s):             2

Why are the Threads = 1 and not = 2?

Comment: I think you're confusing terms. You have threads per core, not per cpu. Then you have a total number of threads per cpu, which for Epyc will be 2x cores, unless for some reason multi threading is disabled. /proc/cpuinfo will show total number of cores running, that includes 'virtual' cores of multithreading. It's rare for ryzen/epyc cpus to not be 2 threads per core however, only the very earliest consumer budget version of ryzen didn't have mt support. If you have 2 cpus that are 32 cores each. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epyc shows what your cpu actually supports.

Comment: lscpu can just be wrong too, by the way, doing cpu logic is getting a lot harder nowadays than it used to be. Try inxi -Cxx and see what it says. lscpu output is confusing, they call a core a cpu, then they call it a core, personally I call the set of cores the cpu, and each processing core a core, that avoids ambiguity. You have 1 or more physical cpus, each of those has 1 or more physical cores, and each of those cores can run 1 or 2 threads, depending on the cpu type.